Get item from quick fix list in neovim
I run some analysis, which outputs errors into quickfix list in neovim. I can then navigate to each error and all works fine. What I need next, is that error message contains some ID, which I need to access. So for example, I navigate to some error, and I can get idx from copen get(getqflist({'idx': 0}), 'idx', 0) which entry it is, but I do not know how to access that error message and take ID from it.
I think the way to do it is to use getqflist function, but I have no idea how.
Example of error message in quickfix list:
src\main.c|161 col 14| ID 3345654 (#1 of 1): MISRA C-2012 Declaration......
And I need that ID number. I want to do some keyboard shortcut that would run function, that can pull out current idx from quickfix list, form there get the ID, and then use this ID to do some stuff (I need to send to server to excuse that error).

You can navigate through the quickfixlist just like any other Vim window, using normal Vim navigation.There's no need to write a custom function using getqlist unless you need to automate the task of sending the ID to the server.

That is exactly what I'm doing. I'm parsing ID and adding some text, then sending it to server. But I already figured it out, as you mentioned, it is Vim window. I use Vim shortcuts to to get to the ID, then copy it and then work with it. Thanks for the comment anyway ;)
